# What is the 'msg' in 'HTML msg' in Elm actually?

Tags: elm, parametric-polymorphism

I'm teaching myself elm and see (of course) many references to `Html msg`--

I understand that this is a 'parameterised type', that is, that (as I understand it), the constructor of the type `Html` takes a parameter -- much as `List Char` does.

OK.  But then in following along in some tutorials, I see they quickly change the `msg` to be a custom type, often something like this (I'm doing this from memory, so please forgive me):

```
Html Msg
```

where `Msg` might be defined as

```
type Msg =
  Something | SomethingElse
```

I also see that here -- https://discourse.elm-lang.org/t/html-msg-vs-html-msg/2758 -- they say

> The lower case msg is called a type variable. The upper case Msg is called a concrete type - its something your application has defined.

That answers my question part way, but could someone elaborate on what this means exactly?  Because when I see something like `List String`,  I understand what `String` is in this context, but I don't understand what `msg` means in `Html msg`.

Also, are we not changing the type of the return value of the function?  That is, if the Elm runtime is expecting `view` to return a certain type, and that type is `Html msg`,  if we change the return type to `Html Whatever`, why does that work?  (For instance, we can't change a function's return value from `List String` to `List Number` arbitrarily, right?)

Coming from a background in OOP and typed languages like C, TypeScript, etc, I would think that any `Msg` would need to somehow be related to `msg`, that is 'extend' it in some way to allow polymorphism.  Obviously I'm looking at this the wrong way, and any explanation would be appreciated!

Comment: I think this has been answered really well here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46038459

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**tl;dr**: as long as every function agrees on the type of `msg`, and `model`, they can be anything you want.

Just like the type parameter of `List`, `msg` can be anything. There is no restriction. To demonstrate, here's the  classic increment/decrement example with the `msg` being just an `Int`:

```hs
-- These type aliases aren't needed, but makes it easier to distinguish
-- their roles in later type signatures
type alias Model = Int
type alias Msg = Int


update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
    model + msg


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div []
        [ button [ onClick 1 ] [ text "+1" ]
        , div [] [ text <| String.fromInt model.count ]
        , button [ onClick (-1) ] [ text "-1" ]
        ]


main : Program () Model Msg
main =
    Browser.sandbox { init = 0, view = view, update = update }
```

So how does that work? The key is in the `Browser.sandbox` function, as that's what connects everything together. Its type signature is:

```
sandbox :
    { init : model
    , view : model -> Html msg
    , update : msg -> model -> model
    }
    -> Program () model msg
```

where `model` and `msg` are type variables. Both of these can be replaced with any concrete type, as long as it matches up with the constraints given in this signature, which is that they must be the same across the `init`, `view` and `update` functions. Otherwise we'll get a type error here. If, for example, `update` requires a `String` instead of an `Int`, we'll get the error:

```
This argument is a record of type:

    { init : Model, update : String -> Model -> Model, view : Model -> Html Msg
    }

But `sandbox` needs the 1st argument to be:

    { init : Model
    , update : String -> Model -> Model
    , view : Model -> Html String
    }
```

It doesn't really know which is right or wrong, of course, just that there's a mismatch. But in an effort to be helpful it assumes `String` is right and expects `view` to return `Html String` instead.

I hope that sufficiently answers your question. If not, comment and subscribe!

Comment: Does one then always need to replace `msg` with your own type?  That is, one could not just leave it `Html msg`, but instead tell the system exactly _what_ kind of message your going to be sending in `view` and receiving in `update`?

Comment: You don't. You can write functions that deal wth any kind of `msg`. That's what `Browser.sandbox` does, after all. It just passes the values around, like a box that can hold anything. You're also not required to use a concrete type with `view` and `update`, but of course that isn't going to be a very useful application. It will be completely static.

Answer (score 3):

#### Short and Simple Explanation:

I have an xmas function like this:

`wrapPresents : presents -> String`

But what is the type, `presents`? It can be anything that you want! You can substitute it with your own 'concrete type'. `presents` is just a place holder!

`wrapPresents : Boxes -> String`

Now we have the "type" - we know that the first parameter must be a `Box` type.

`wrapPresents boxes = "All the boxes are now wrapped!"`

### Summary: msg (lowercase) is simply a placeholder